# Remapping Ctrl+[key] combos to Meta+[key] in LXQT (Lubuntu 19.04)

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

I use Mac for work, Meta+C/V seems a much saner combination to me than having to use Shift in terminal because of SIGINT. I'm trying to remap the Ctrl+C/V combos in LXQT to mac-like Windows/Command+C/V, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. What I have tried so far is adding a new global binding to `Shortcut Keys` app:

```
xclip -out -selection primary | xclip -in -selection clipboard
```

[image]

This command seems to work great in terminal but has no effect in the Shortcuts App, almost as if the app is spawned in a sandbox. The idea behind it is to copy the primary clipboard (auto-populated on text selection) into the more sane/permanent clipboard that works similar to OSX. I'm not attached to the above command, if there is a cleaner way to remap `Ctrl` keys in LXQT, I'll do it. In Awesome WM, I simply added them into my `rc.lua`. I did check `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` but don't see anything relevant there. Also, is it possible to integrate this with qlipper?

Comment: The Lubuntu manual highlights global shortcuts override others (openbox is used as the example in the manual) so have you tried using Gloabl-Key shortcuts (Global Actions Manager found in the menu; also under *shortcuts keys*  (https://manual.lubuntu.me/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html)

Comment: Yes, the `Shortcut Keys` tool I mentioned above is exactly the same Global-Keys tool you mention. Its GUI name is `Shortcut Keys`. I added a picture to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say SIGINT instead of INTC